# error showing to connecting the database

Tags: mysql

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'update_time' in 'order clause'.

The SQL statement executed was:

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, 
       `t`.`title` AS `t0_c1`, 
       `t`.`content` AS `t0_c2`, 
       `t`.`status` AS `t0_c3`, 
       `t`.`tags` AS `t0_c4`, 
       `t`.` update_time` AS `t0_c5`, 
       `t`.`create_time` AS `t0_c6`, 
       `t`.`author_id` AS `t0_c7` 
  FROM `post` `t` 
 WHERE (status=2) 
 ORDER BY update_time DESC 
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What's the problem??? the error is pretty clear, you don't have any column called `update_time`

Comment: which part of this message is not clear to you?

Comment: Is the column name in the table `' update_time'` or `'update_time'` ? There is leading space in column name in your query.

Comment: i created and post table shows both update_time and create_Time

Comment: post the table and some data in sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the column by it's alias:

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, 
   `t`.`title` AS `t0_c1`, 
   `t`.`content` AS `t0_c2`, 
   `t`.`status` AS `t0_c3`, 
   `t`.`tags` AS `t0_c4`, 
   `t`.`update_time` AS `t0_c5`, 
   `t`.`create_time` AS `t0_c6`, 
   `t`.`author_id` AS `t0_c7` 
FROM `post` `t` 
WHERE (`t`.`status`=2) 
ORDER BY `t`.`update_time` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the table name itself with the column names just like

```
 WHERE (t.status=2)   //replace this line in your code
 ORDER BY t.update_time DESC  //replace this line in your code
```

Comment: it will shows #1054 - Unknown column 't.update_time' in 'field list'

Comment: @user3436639 why dont you post the table and some data in http://sqlfiddle.com so that we can see whats wrong in there.

Comment: Schema Creation Failed: Table 'db_2_90d92.post' doesn't exist:

Comment: put the schema to your question then

Comment: Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not foun' at line 1:

Comment: do you have access to database if yes just get the table structure and post to your question or if you are using PHP myadmin you can get the table structure.